# Google Cloud Datalab on Google Cloud Platform loses all variables if I lose my ssh connection

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

If I run a computation on Google Cloud Datalab and for some reason lose the ssh connection to my local machine, I can reestablish the ssh connection to the workbook, but it seems like the kernel has restarted.  All variables that were in memory are lost.

Steps to reproduce:
I start Google Cloud Datalab with launching a VM:

> mango$ gcloud compute instances create "instance-name" \
>     --project "project-id" \
>     --zone "zone" \
>     --network "datalab-network" \
>     --image-family "container-vm" \
>     --image-project "google-containers" \
>     --metadata "google-container-manifest=$(cat datalab-server.yaml)" \
>     --machine-type "n1-highmem-4" --scopes "cloud-platform"

But customizing the variables.
Then I launch ssh via

> mango$   gcloud compute ssh --quiet   --project "project-id"   --zone "us-west1-b"   --ssh-flag="-N"   --ssh-flag="-L"   --ssh-flag="localhost:8081:localhost:8080"   "${USER}@instance-name"

And finally connect to the localhost.
I can then connect, define variables and start my compute process.  As expected, I can open a second browser window via the same ssh session and check with the kernel that my variables are in memory.  But if I lose my ssh connection, when I reconnect it is like I am connecting to a new kernel or the kernel restarted.

Is there a way to come back to the same kernel, as if I were using a linux screen command?

Comment: It works fine for me. When you reconnect your SSH tunnel, and open the sessions page (http://localhost:8081/sessions), do you see any kernels still running?